# translate() vs top/left for positioning

Tags: css, css-position

From what I find, `translate()` seems to offer smoother animations over plain `top/left` but my question is related to a CSS layout I saw recently. The author used the following setting to position a block of text inside the main header image:

```
.hero-text-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

He didn't explain, and I'm left wondering what advantage `translate()` has over `top/left` in percentage values when it comes to pure layouts (i.e., no animation). I'm guessing this really doesn't matter in the case of layouts, and was the result of the author's habits. But even then, this combines both `top/left` and `translate()`. What's going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you posted is used to position an element vertically and horizontally centered. `translate` is used here because the percentage are relative to the element dimensions. The percentage values for top and left with `position: absolute` are relative to the dimensions of the first parent element with `position` set to `relative, absolute or fixed`.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thank you! :-) I'll accept this as the answer as soon SO allows me to.